# Addup specific value from array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating small project for practice in React. My idea is too show number of portion that is in cart near the cart icon (classic like in every e-commerce app) but I am not sure how to do this. I tried using useEffect and useState combination but it didnt worked or at least I didnt managed to set it up correct, I have useState like this:

```
const [numberOfPortion, setNumberOfPortion] = useState(0);
```

And objects I put in Cart look like this:

```
[{
foodName: "Chicken Wingos"
foodPrice: 45
numberOfPortions: 2
},
{
foodName: "Chicken curry"
foodPrice: 50
numberOfPortions: 1
}]
```

So, what is the best was to take every number of portion and add it togethere to show near cart icon in this case that would be "3". Should I use useState and useEffect here or is there any better solution? I accept any idea since I rly am not sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the easiest way to get it.

```
let num = 0;
for (let i in arr) num+=arr[i].numberOfPortions;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function

```
const myArray = [{
    foodName: "Chicken Wingos"
    foodPrice: 45
    numberOfPortions: 2
  },
  {
    foodName: "Chicken curry"
    foodPrice: 50
    numberOfPortions: 1
  }]

const totalPortions = myArray.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value.numberOfPortions, 0);
```

Comment: While using ur solution I get "Reduce of empty array with no initial value"

Comment: You will have to pass a default initial value after the reduce function. I updated the answer